# What's the purpose of automatically added bridge component after router?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

After visualizing my flow (using [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-flo/tree/angular-1.x/samples/spring-flo-si) great project, btw.), I've noticed that there are `bridge` components (together with `DirectChannel`s) inserted right after my `router`:

[image: flow visualization]

My DSL configuration:

```
.route(Message.class, messageTypeHeader(), mapping -> mapping
    .id("filteringRouterEndpoint")
    .resolutionRequired(false)
    .defaultSubFlowMapping(rejectedByFiltersFlow)
    .subFlowMapping(MessageType.TYPE_1, s -> s
            .channel("type1MappingChannel")
            .filter(type1MappingFilter)
            .channel(ACCEPTED_BY_FILTERS_CHANNEL_NAME))
    .subFlowMapping(MessageType.TYPE_2, s -> s
            .channel("type2MappingChannel")
            .filter(type2MappingFilter)
            .channel(ACCEPTED_BY_FILTERS_CHANNEL_NAME))
    .subFlowMapping(MessageType.TYPE_3, s -> s
            .channel("type3MappingChannel")
            .filter(type3MappingFilter)
            .channel(ACCEPTED_BY_FILTERS_CHANNEL_NAME)))
```

(some names are different than on the flow, just to simplify)

I've noticed, that if I don't specify the channels explicitly on the beginning of the mapping subflows (i.e. `typeXMappingChannel`s), then the bridges aren't created:
[image: flow visualization 2]

but I want to specify channels by myself, just to know their exact name, or to have other than `DirectChannel` implementation for example.

What is the reason for that? Or maybe I made something wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an artifact of how the flow is constructed.

When we call `.subflowMapping()` we start to build a flow that begins with a channel. Since we haven't encountered the first element of the flow yet `.channel()` in your case, we build a default input channel.

Then, when we encounter the `.channel()` we see the previous component is a channel, so we bridge it.

We could possibly optimize it out for this specific case; I'll take a look, but it will likely be a 5.2 change if we do it.

[GH-2890](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2890)

Comment: The workaround for you is to defile all those sub-flow lambdas as separate `@Bean IntegrationFlow`. Then their `inputChannel` is going to be resolved properly and no additional channel and bridges will be created.

Comment: I think we need to treat this as *Works as Designed*. It is now you have a `channel()` in the  "beginning" of the sub-flow, but then eventually you'll decide to add something else before. Essentially this is definitely not a start of the flow. This is something in the middle. And that's exactly the case why we have introduce a feature like flow bean injection as a sub-flows. I would say that we just need to document this behavior and show in docs how to overcome if that.

Comment: Thank you guys for the clarification! Yes, maybe some note in docs would be useful :)